# mysql select left join multi tables sum & group by gives repeated answer

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, left-join

I have three tables

Table 1 : item

```
id  item
5   pen
6   pencil
```

Table 2: purchase

```
id  item    qty    item_id
1   pen     10     5
2   pencil  10     6
3   pen     10     5
```

Table 3: sale

```
id  item    qty    item_id
1   pen     5      5
```

I want the result as follows :

Required result :

```
item    purchase    sale    stock
pen     20          5       15
pencil  10          0       10
```

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT P.item, P.purchase, IFNULL(S.sale, 0), P.purchase - IFNULL(S.sale, 0) stock
FROM (SELECT item, SUM(qty) purchase
      FROM purchase
      GROUP BY item) P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item, SUM(qty) sale
           FROM sale
           GROUP BY item) S ON P.item = S.item
```

Comment: Result from above query :

item    purchase    sale    stock
pen     20              5        15
pencil  10             NULL   NULL

It shows perfectly when there is value of sale. But if there is no sale value, it should show stock as 10 in case of pencil whereas it says NULL. Please help